# Ansible Five random hosts from /etc/ansible/hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have this playbook, it work using max_index  but always takes  the first 3 hosts from /etc/ansible/hosts , i need to take 3 random (and not repeated) hosts from that file.

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: ciscos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=limited_selection
      when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) < max_index | int

- hosts: limited_selection
  gather_facts: no
```

**/etc/ansible/hosts**

```
[ciscos]
stagin ansible_host=10.xx.xx.1
stagin2 ansible_host=10.xx.xx.1
stagin3 ansible_host=10.xx.xx.1
stagin4 ansible_host=10.xx.xx.1
stagin5 ansible_host=10.xx.xx.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

You need to shuffle the elements of the group and choose three first. The Jinja2 expression for that is:

```
(groups['ciscos'] | shuffle)[0:3]
```

---

**Implementation which should work, but has problems**

You should be able to simply filter the group in the `hosts` declaration:

```
- hosts: "{{ (groups['ciscos'] | shuffle)[0:3] }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

However the results are undeterministic - although the play shows as running against three randomly chosen hosts, the tasks are sometimes executed on 1, 2, 3, or 0:

```
PLAY [[u'stagin2', u'stagin4', u'stagin5']] *******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [stagin2] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [stagin5] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

---

**Workaround (implementation which works)**

Use `add_host` module to create a filtered group:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: limited_selection
      loop:  "{{ (groups['ciscos'] | shuffle)[0:3] }}"

- hosts: limited_selection
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Comment: its not working
fatal: [stagin]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{ (groups['ciscos'] | shuffle)[0:3] }}' in the available lookup plugins"}

Comment: Which Ansible version are you running?

Comment: ansible --version
ansible 2.2.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides

Comment: How about using current version?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
---
- hosts: ciscos
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: Fact My Inventory
      set_fact:
        myinventory: "{{ ansible_play_batch | shuffle }}"
      run_once: True
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Fact limited_selection
      set_fact:
        limited_selection: "{{ myinventory[0:max_index|int] }}"
      run_once: True
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Create Inventory
      add_host:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        groups: limited_selection
      with_items: "{{ limited_selection }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

- hosts: limited_selection
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "I'm in the limited selection group!"
```

Be careful with `play_hosts` as it is deprecated.

> **Note**: I have kept the playbook with `connection:ciscos` instead of `localhost` for learning purposes and showing the `ansible_play_batch` and `max_index` variables. It is better to have a localhost play with `groups` instead of `delegate_to:localhost`